# How to run a single python function in parallel multiple times

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-multiprocessing

I have a python function which I want to run 100 times in parallel. What is the code to do that

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"')
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'c:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
def true():
    driver.get('https://youtu.be/Uhr5J5Sj-fU')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[2]/button/div').click()
    time.sleep(12*60+30)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Which part of your code do you want to run 100 times in parallel? The [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module will probably be of interest to you.

Comment: The true() function

Comment: Would you also mind posting what you've attempted so far to run your code in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use threading module of python
This may help you

```py
import threading
def hi():
    print('hi')
for i in range(0,100):
    t= threading.Thread(target=hi)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Just a heads up, the threading module might not offer true parallelism because of the Global Interpreter Lock in CPython implementations.

Comment: Bruh that is greek to me

Comment: @KeshavReddy--Explained in more detail [here](https://timber.io/blog/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-in-python-what-you-need-to-know/), but basically means that multi-threading doesn't speed up CPU intensive operations.

Comment: No that is not intensive at all. I am willing to run that function 10 times in parallel and is using less than 20% of my cpu